# Center and resize carousel caption with image Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing around with carousel to make it work with images without stretching.

I am trying set caption within the carousel so it doesn't escape from the image and mix with white background.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 800px;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/A83qNiV.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OlbCjdA.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wwOoOIc.png" alt="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If the question is, how to make the caption fit: play with the left and right percentages for .carousel-caption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for input.
I have found solution which suits my needs.

Here it is:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 800px;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
  top: 30%;

 
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/A83qNiV.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OlbCjdA.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wwOoOIc.png" alt="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

I have used resizable font to get it done.

```
h1 {
   font-size: 5.9vw;

}
h2 {
   font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
   font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add below class in css

```
.carousel-caption {
    background-color: #00F;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```